# Nginx proxy use path(subpath) as url

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

My demand is as follows:

If I request an URL like this

> http://example.com/10-10-43-3

the server gets the resource from

> http://10.10.43.3

and response to me.

10-10-43-3 can be arbitrary URL that replace '.' with '-'.

How can I achieve it through nginx? Something like location and proxy_pass?

Answer (score 0):

The following should help get you started.

```
location /10-10-43-3 {
  proxy_pass http://10.10.43.3;
}
```

If there are other redirects that need to be accounted for, you will most likely need to add variations to the above as well as regular expression handling.